PHP mail function sends to Gmail but not to some other domains
I have php mail() implemented but it sends only to gmail not to other domains. I have multiple recipient on mail code.
I want that it should send mails to the given recipient. I have below code and that is not sending mail to my recipients.
<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

        // set recipient email address 
        $to = "abanks@balticcapitalpartners.com, success@balticcapitalpartners.com, prasant@nfty.property";
    
        // set email subject 
        $subject = "New Form Submission";
    
        // compose email
        $message = '<html><body>';
        $message .= '<h2>Do I qualify Form Submission</h2>';
        $message .= '<p><strong>First Name:</strong> ' . $_POST["firstName"] . '</p>';
        $message .= '<p><strong>Last Name:</strong> ' . $_POST["lastName"] . '</p>';
        $message .= '<p><strong>City:</strong> ' . $_POST["city"] . '</p>';
        $message .= '<p><strong>Country:</strong> ' . $_POST["country"] . '</p>';
        $message .= '<p><strong>Citizenship:</strong> ' . $_POST["citizenship"] . '</p>';
        $message .= '<p><strong>Age:</strong> ' . $_POST["age"] . '</p>';
        $message .= '<p><strong>Mobile:</strong> ' . $_POST["mobile"] . '</p>';
        $message .= '<p><strong>Email:</strong> ' . $_POST["emailInfo"] . '</p>';
        $message .= '<p><strong>Notes:</strong> ' . $_POST["notes"] . '</p>';
        $message .= '<p><strong>Information Regarding:</strong> ' . $_POST["informationRegarding"] . '</p>';
        $message .= '</body></html>';

        $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: ' . $_POST['emailInfo'] . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $_POST['emailInfo'] . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Cc: success@balticcapitalpartners.com' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    
        // send email
        $success = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

        if (!$success) {
            echo "Email sending failed";
            echo "Error: " . error_get_last()['message'];
        }
    }
?>


Is it not sending or not being received

Most mail servers will not send email if the from address is not a registered email user on the sending site. You are using an email you get from the form. That is probably not a valid email address on your sending server

You're basically allowing your app to forge emails from whatever email address is in the POSTed input data. Unsurprisingly most mail servers don't like it when you attempt to impersonate somebody else's email account - your server doesn't have permission to create emails on their behalf! So it'll probably drop those mails most of the time. Do it a lot and mailservers will start to blacklist you. Instead use a fixed "from" address in your code which matches the domain you're sending from (e.g. noreply@yourdomain.com), and include the submitted address in the message body and/or reply-to field

@RiggsFolly not being received.

Most likely the receiving server is checking back to your server to see if the FROM address is valid and getting a "No its Not" So throwing the email away. Look up SPF, DKIM and DMARC. Most servers are being a lot more careful delivering emails to try and stem the flow of SPAM

Did you fix the FROM address or just ignore the other comments?

@RiggsFolly I just fixed the Reply-to, what do I need to fix in FROM address?

Your FROM should be an address this server is "allowed" to send mails for. If you have this code running on balticcapitalpartners.com, then using an address from that domain should probably work.

what do I need to fix in FROM address...pretty sure I already explained what to do in my earlier comment, too! Read back through everything - and look at the duplicate question too, where this is also mentioned in the main answer.

@CBroe I have running my code on this balticcapitalpartners.co is that make any difference?

So use a FROM address "from" that domain then - something like noreply@balticcapitalpartners.co(m)

@CBroe You mean in the above code where headers are written?

Yes, of course - where else would the From address be specified in that given code ...?
